# How to create a list of options when typing?

Tags: html

It's a pretty newbie and straightforward problem: while the user is typing, how to make the possible answers appear beneath it, kinda like the option tag, but in a input. Not necessarily based on things the user wrote before and are stored on his browser, more like when Google suggests something.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Thanks, haven't though about the 'autocomplete' term.

Comment: Three upvotes for a question that shows no research or attempt at solving with any code?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried datalist

```
<datalist id="cars">
<option value="volvo">
<option value="benz">  

</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a div or span that is styled

```
display:none;
```

or

```
visibility:hidden;
```

Then use javascript to launch a function when the user changes something in the textbox

```
<input type="text" onchange="myFunction()">
```

In the javascript function set the style of the div

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility="visible";
```

And also use whatever algorithm you want to add data to the div

```
suggestionData = function() { super algorithm here};

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=suggestionData;
```